# RSA Authentication: Cannot get passwordless login with SSH

Tags: ssh, rsa

I have set up my computer to do the public/private authentication with a remote server, but somehow it is not working today.

I have done the ssh key-gen -t rsa, then scp'd it to the remote.

I can scp without a password (using the pub/priv key), but whenever I try to SSH, it requests the password.

What can I do to authenticate on the key alone?

Comment: Does te server requires pass for the Key or for your username? (Should be indicated : pass for key xxx)

Comment: Where/How would I check this?

Comment: Does the prompt only says : Password: or something like Enter passphrase for key '/home/xxx'

Comment: Oh, it asks for "user@remote's password," so the username.

Comment: What does `ssh -v ...` say? It mostly shows you where the problem is. Also, show us `ls -la ~/.ssh`.

Comment: ...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: ~/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: ~/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
[requests password]

Comment: and the permissions on .ssh are all good to go.

Comment: For the record, the term and sshd option "RSA Authentication" belong to obsolete SSHv1. In SSHv2, "Public key authentication" or "PubkeyAuthentication" are used.

Answer (score 6):

You should check if you have (sshd_config) :

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

UsePAM yes  <-- That one is usually the last line of the sshd_config
```

Then that your public key is added to authorized_keys in your `~/.ssh/`.
The last one (`UsePAM yes`) is very important, since if disabled it will force you to authenticate with your unix account. PAM is here to say that private key authentication is sufficient to log in.
Eventually, if that still don't resolves you may have to check the PAM configuration.

Comment: I think working scp illustrates that the proble is on the client side, not on the server's one.

Comment: UsePAM is "yes" and everything in my pam.conf file is commented out.  Any more help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you specify the key manually with -i ? or with a directive in .ssh/config? Do you have a pam_sshd or pam_ssh in the /etc/pam.d/ directory? What are you using for ssh and scp client: command line? GUI? Linux/Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your public key on the server to the authorized keys:

```
ssh-keygen -i -f keyfilename.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

or

```
cat keyfilename.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Answer (score 1):

First, On remote server:

> /usr/sbin/sshd -de -p 1234

Second, On your computer:

> ssh -vp 1234

You may find the error.

Or you can post them here.

Answer (score 0):

If you can scp with the key but not ssh, it sounds like your scp client can find the key, but the ssh client can't.

Since you mentioned `ssh-keygen -t rsa` I'm going to assume that you're using OpenSSH on UNIX of some kind and you saved the key in the default location in some user account.

Are you logged in as user other than the one with the key (e.g. `su`ed or `sudo`ed) when you're running the ssh client? If you need to ssh without a password from that account also, you'll probably want to use `ssh-keygen` in that account, and then put that account's public ssh key in the remote server's authorized keys file along side the other one.